# MIME type of .R files

Tags: r, wordpress, mime-types

There is no information on what MIME types .R files are. I checked on https://www.filesuffix.com/en/extension/r but the MIME type 'application/octet-stream' doesn't work when adding .R extension to the approved file formats for WordPress upload. I also used mime package for R, it results in 'text/plain' but it also doesn't work. Any idea what the correct MIME type for .R files is?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/mime-types-complete-list/) there appears to be no mime type defined for .r files. I would use just `text/plain`.

Comment: Does not work in what context? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I'm trying to enable wordpress users to upload their .R code files. I have allowed different types of files to pass through the firewall, including .R files. I'm using the File Upload Types plugin by WPForms to allow specific file formats plus I modified wp-config.php with define( 'ALLOW_UNFILTERED_UPLOADS', true ); This works well for Python and Java code files but I can't get it to work with .R file. It's probably MIME type that is wrong or unsupported by WordPress.